# list post in categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a a post model and a categories model

**I want to show a list the all posts by category all on one page.**

I am using has and belong_to in each model correctly.

I just cant fiqure out how to show them in my view.

Want I need is

**Category Name**

- Post1
- Post2
- Post3

**Category Name2**

- Post1
- Post2
- Post3

etc...

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your controller set @categories:

```
@categories = Category.find(:all, :include => :posts) # you may specify your conditions here
# :include is needed to avoid a query on each "category.posts" call later in the view
```

Then in the view:

```
<% for category in @categories %>
  <strong><%= category.name %></strong>
  <ul>
    <% for post in category.posts %>
      <li><%= post.name %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You could also use the `group_by` method on `Enumerable` for the view code.  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#M002570

Comment: I'd add :include => :posts to the Category.find call to eliminate the n+1 query problem. The version here will work, but it will hit the database for each category to get it's posts. Using :include causes ActiveRecord to do a join when it generates the SQL query.